# Laggy whenever updating state on a dynamically generated form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i have this simple form data here, stored on a util file.

```
const Data = {
    prop1: '',
    prop2: '',
    prop3: '',
    prop4: '',
    prop5: '',
    prop6: ''
}
```

Then based on the form data above, i generated the form for each property. To update the form, i created a custom hook to update the form data whenever a textfield is updated.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Data } from 'somewhere';
import { Grid, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';

/* Custom object updater hook */
const useDataUpdater = data => {
    const [obj, setObj] = useState(data);

    const updateHandler = (key, value) => {
        setObj({ ...obj, [key]: value });
    }

    return { obj, updateHandler};
}

const Form = props => {
    const FormObj = useDataUpdater(Data);

    return (
        <Grid container direction="row">
            {
                Object.keys(FormObj.obj).map(key => (
                    <Grid key={'form_' + key} item xs={7}>
                        <TextField value={FormObj.obj[key]} onChange={evt => FormObj.updateHandler(key, evt.target.value)}></TextField>
                    </Grid>
                ))
            }
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

When i do this, whenever i want to update a textfield, it feels laggy to type. From what i read, this is caused by the re-rendering of the whole form again whenever the state is being updated.

Is there a way to optimize it so that it won't feel laggy anymore? I want to make it dynamic like this, because of the nature of the form data that is dynamic, and i don't want to create separate component file just to cater for each form of the form data. I also don't want to hard code every textfield on the file, especially if i need to do it for a form data with lots of properties inside it.

Comment: onChange={evt => FormObj.updateHandler(key, evt.target.value)} This function make llazy

Comment: you should take a look at react memoize `https://medium.com/@rossbulat/how-to-memoize-in-react-3d20cbcd2b6e`